# Change Firefox profile path via script?

Tags: firefox, profile, fedora, nfs

I'm working on something of a hack because FF has so much trouble (super slow) starting up because our mozilla profile is on our NFS servers. Is there any way in the startup scripts of FF to edit the default profile?

My hack idea is to cp the mozilla profile to a local directory which will allow for quicker opening, then as changes are made do an rsync. Mostly, right now, I'm worried about finding a way to change the default path via script for the profiles, I have an idea as to syncing and so forth.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_manager lets you specify custom profile location

Comment: Was trying to script the change as opposed to using a GUI - adminning a few hundred people's changes and this is needed for an update we're working on.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could create a symbolic link for each user, at $HOME/.mozilla that points to your local directory where you have copied the files.  Firefox would then only be reading that one link from the NFS server.

Comment: Yea that's not a bad idea only problem is that we're planning this is if its somewhat unlikely that the user will be on the same computer he was last which means we'd have to find a way to send old .mozilla files across the network.